# Which object do I use?

Tags: java

I don't understand which object I should put inside the identifier for Wind beaufort = new Wind(___);. The first line of code here is the constructor and the second is the class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WindSpeedCalc
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Wind speed in km/h: ");
        double kmH = scanner.nextDouble();
        
        
        Wind wind = new Wind(kmH);
        System.out.printf("The wind speed is equivalent to %.2f knots to two decimal places\n", wind.calculateKnots());
        Wind beaufort = new Wind(idkk);
        System.out.printf("The wind speed ranks around a %.1f on the Beaufort Scale\n", wind.calculateB());
        
        System.out.print(wind.analyzeWind());
    }
    
}
```

This is the class that connects to the constructor above. I don't believe there is anything wrong with this one.

```
public class Wind
{
    double kmH;
    final double KM_IN_MI = 1.852;

    public Wind(double speedKmH)
    {
        kmH = speedKmH;
    }
    public double calculateKnots()
    {
        double knots = kmH / KM_IN_MI;
        return knots;
    }
    
    public int calculateB()
    {
         double mS = kmH / 3.6;
         double pow = 2.0 / 3.0;
         int b = (int)Math.round(Math.pow((mS / 0.836), pow));
         if(b > 12)
          b = 12;
         return b; 
    }
    
    public String analyzeWind()
    {
        String s = "";
        if(kmH < 2)
            s = "Wind is calm";
        else if (kmH > 120) 
            s = "European storm";
        else 
            s = "Moderate to strong wind";
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not need a second `Wind` object, if you don't have a different speed value to use. Just use one `Wind` object and call your methods on it.

Comment: Hint: Take a look at `public int calculateB()` method. How can you call it? What it returns?

Comment: But isn't the Wind considered as the Class?

Comment: You are getting confused with *classes* an *objects*. `Wind` is your *class*. A class is essential a blueprint for *objects*. You are currently creating two objects `wind` (lowercase w) and `beaufort`. You can read more here https://www.javatpoint.com/difference-between-object-and-class

Comment: Do you think you could give me little hint?

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the first object to access the method calculateB() without declaring another object**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WindSpeedCalc
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Wind speed in km/h: ");
        double kmH = scanner.nextDouble();
        
        Wind wind = new Wind(kmH);
        System.out.printf("The wind speed is equivalent to %.2f knots to two decimal places\n", wind.calculateKnots());
        System.out.printf("The wind speed ranks around a %.1f on the Beaufort Scale\n", (double)wind.calculateB());
        
        System.out.print(wind.analyzeWind());
    }
}
```

**Or** if you want to declare a new object for some reasons, you can just pass the same variable "kmH" as the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WindSpeedCalc
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Wind speed in km/h: ");
        double kmH = scanner.nextDouble();
        
        Wind wind = new Wind(kmH);
        System.out.printf("The wind speed is equivalent to %.2f knots to two decimal places\n", wind.calculateKnots());
        Wind beaufort = new Wind(kmH);
        System.out.printf("The wind speed ranks around a %.1f on the Beaufort Scale\n", (double)beaufort.calculateB());
        
        System.out.print(wind.analyzeWind());
    }
}
```

Comment: Um not to be rude, but the first one is something that I've already tried, it would give me an error when I run it.

Comment: The error is java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer
 at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4426)
 at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2951)
 at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2898)
 at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2673)
 at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1053)
 at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:949)
 at WindSpeedCalc.main(WindSpeedCalc.java:18)

Comment: @GeorgeParker You are receiving the error because your calculateB() method returns an integer, and you're giving it a format for a float. Just stick a double cast in front of it, it should be fine

Comment: Edit this line to be: 
System.out.printf("The wind speed ranks around a %.1f on the Beaufort Scale\n", (double)wind.calculateB());